# Change edittext line color for single control?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an edittext that resides on a dark background. The design for the screen calls for an edittext with a while line and white text in order to be visible. I figured this would be an easy task, but I've run into an issue.

I looked on StackOverflow already for the question, but all the answers basically point to changing the style of all edittext controls across the entire app; that isn't an option, as this will affect only 2 on a single screen.

I tried the following, but neither the line nor hint are white; instead both are still black. The text is, however, white when I type something into the control.

```
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_login"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:drawableBottom="#FFFFFF"
            />
```

The drawableBottom and textColorHint were both attempts to color the line and hint text white.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I'm missing here? Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For when you are targeting API 21 and above, you should use the backgroundTint attribute:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:hint="@string/hint_login"

    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/white"

    android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorPrimaryDark2"

    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:singleLine="true"

    />
```

If you are targeting API levels lower than 21 you should use a custom drawable to change the underline. You can easily create a nine-patch image from [this site](http://android-holo-colors.com/) and then use that as your view's background.

Comment: This ended up being exactly what I needed! Thank you very much =D

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a `EditText` on `"black" background` . You can change the code according to your background.

Create a xml file which will be set as a background of the EditText.
The xml file say `bg.xml` will look like -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:top="-2dp" android:left="-2dp" android:right="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffffffff" />
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" /> //Change this color according to your background
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

And your EditText should be -

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/text_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hint_login"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple workaround for this issue. You can use a EditText with transparent background and with a view at its bottom. Set the color of that view and it would look like a line.

[image]

**Layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="30dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:hint="Hint here"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/editTextBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Happy Coding :)